# Is my 3DS Bricked?

Tags: technical-issues, nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, homebrew

I was installing arm9loaderhax (at http://2xrsa.3ds.guide) and it didn't turn off. I waited an hour, pressed <kbd>A</kbd> button and <kbd>Select</kbd> and nothing happened.

I removed the SD card and powered on, the screen had some color changing but I switched off Power-Saving Mode and the screen is fine.

I then formatted the SD card - (it said that the sd card was corrupted in my pc). Now I am at 2.2.1 version - my 3ds works but I don't know how to get out of it. Is it bricked? [Here is my n3ds without sd card.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmlZH.jpg)

Comment: 'Bricked' means that the device (your 3DS) won't turn on (or wont boot at all) - is this the case? Can you get to the main 3DS menu?

Comment: Yes I powered on my n3ds right now without SD card and its working fine, problem is I cant close it because its a rule not to close n3ds while in 2.2.1 version it can brick it

Comment: why will it be bricked if you update?

Comment: @Aequitas Basically the arm9loaderhax install guide downgrades the New 3DS to the Old 3DS's FW. If you update from 2.1 manually it doesn't work and the device will brick because you're trying to update to the newest Old 3DS FW (or something to those lines.)

Comment: Reopening based on: [What's the official stance on hacked/modded consoles?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258/whats-the-official-stance-on-hacked-modded-consoles): Homebrew/Mods for 3DS are allowed here.

Answer (score 5):

As cited from [3ds.guide](https://3ds.guide/troubleshooting#ts_browser):

> ## A browser based exploit is not working
>
> Browser based exploits (such as browserhax or 2xrsa) are often unstable and crash frequently, but they can sometimes be fixed by doing the following steps
>
> Launch the browser, then launch the browser settings
> Scroll to the bottom and Initialize Savedata (it also may be called Clear All Save Data)
> Try the exploit again

[Redo this step](https://3ds.guide/installing-arm9loaderhax) and use the backed up NAND.bin from the previous step. If you didn't back that up, you're screwed.